# Velocity variation in the circular motion of a material point moving in counterclockwise motion

Tags: solution-verification, physics, mathematical-physics

Suppose that a material point instead of move itself along a circle in clockwise direction as shown in the figure moves, instead, in counterclockwise direction.

[image]

$$
\vec{v}_1=(v \cos(π−ϕ)){\bf \hat x}+(v \sin(π−ϕ))  {\bf \hat y} $$
and
$$\vec{v}_2=(v \cos(π+ϕ)){\bf \hat x}+(v \sin(π+ϕ)) {\bf \hat y}$$

I must to find the quantity $-2(v \sin(ϕ)) {\bf \hat y}$. In fact

$$\overrightarrow{\Delta v}=\vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_1 = (-v \cos(ϕ)){\bf \hat x}-(v \sin(ϕ)) {\bf \hat y} + v \cos(ϕ) {\bf \hat x} -(v \sin(ϕ)) {\bf \hat y}=-2(v \sin(ϕ)) {\bf \hat y}$$

Please, are they correct my steps?

Comment: @KeithMcClary Thank you for your feedback. Now I have improved the figure.

Comment: yup! it checks out

Comment: @caverac Weee. hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii $\ddot \smile$$\ddot \smile$$\ddot \smile$$\ddot \smile$ sometimes write also to me $\ddot \smile$$\ddot \smile$$\ddot \smile$.. My best best regards.

Comment: Sebastiano my friend! I hope you're doing well, best regards

Comment: @caverac Dearest Caverac I always try to do my best even if my health is not optimal. I always wish you my best with all my heart. Greetings.